# when i try to upload a contract with remix i get error on gas estimate Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Tags: remix, gas, error, bsc

When uploading a project from remix (bsc testnet) i get this msg,

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

i get to sent the IterableMapping contract to testnet, but the token contract it wont let me sent, both contracts are compiled in the same file

Now i have tried with a few differnt contracts and i run into this problem several times. so just for a test, i took a contract allready up on the mainnet, without changeing anything in the contract and i get the same problem again. been trying several differnt contracts and same error pup up.

Why im i getting this error ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Is it a contract that has functions that require a fee in token to get executed? if yes and the contract is deployed, send an amount the token to the contract address. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Its a reward token, i have uploaded reward tokens before, and i checked this specific project i just copied (for the lenght and complicity of the contract is semilar to my own code) this was uploaded normally. also how i only have been able to get the IterableMapping contract up, i have no tokens to sent to the contract. so that can not be the solution/issue

Comment: send the address of the contract so that I can try it myself and see if I will resolve the issue